# What's the difference between Skip-gram word2vec and CBOW w2v during training with gensim library?

Tags: python, machine-learning, nlp, gensim, word2vec

For Skip-gram word2vec training samples are obtained as follows:

```
Sentence: The fox was running across the maple forest
```

The word `fox` give next pairs for training:

```
fox-run, fox-across, fox-maple, fox-forest
```

and etc. for every word. CBOW w2v use reverse approach:

```
run-fox, across-fox, maple-fox, forest-fox
```

or for `forest` word:

```
fox-forest, run-forest, across-forest, maple-forest
```

So we get all the pairs. What's the difference between Skip-gram word2vec and CBOW w2v during training with gensim library, if we do not specify the target word when training in the CBOW-mode? In both cases all pairs of words are used, or not?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Only skip-gram uses training pairs of the form `(context_word)->(target_word)`.

In CBOW, the training examples are `(average_of_multiple_context_words)->(target_word)`. So, when the error from a single training example is backpropagated, multiple context-words get the same corrective nudge.

Comment: Thanks! Can you explain what is `average_of_multiple_context_words` and how does it work?

Comment: I found explanation of `average_of_multiple_context_words` here https://www.analyticsvidhya.com/blog/2017/06/word-embeddings-count-word2veec/ , thanks